# Can't boot laptop after installing tlp

Tags: boot, tlp

I just installed tlp to save power and when I started it the laptop froze I tried to shut it down but it didn't respond so I forced stop it by holding the power button and now when I boot my laptop the screen just stays black and nothing appears...but I can access grub tho can you help me to boot my laptop

Answer (score 1):

From the grub menu select **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** submenu. From there select **Recovery** option.

After logging in (graphics resolution might be reduced) open a terminal and use

```
sudo apt remove tlp --purge
```

Then reboot and select normal grub start option for Ubuntu.

Next step (different question) is to find out what makes `tlp` incompatible with your system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to uninstall tlp? Maybe gdm3 display manager is broken. You could try to install other display manager.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> simultaneously (You could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back)
2. Log in
3. `$ sudo apt purge tlp`
4. `$ sudo reboot`
   If did not help, try
5. `$ sudo apt purge gdm3` (if gdm3 is installed)
6. `$ sudo apt install lightdm` (it could prompt to select display manager by default if there are a few of them)
7. `$ sudo reboot`

Also, you could search for proprietary video card drivers. Maybe tlp could not work with your default video drivers.